# Should we remove HTML attributes while using Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm studying Thymeleaf and have found out that in almost all examples there are Thymeleaf's tag values as well as standard HTML values like:

```
<title th:text="#{product.page.title}">Page Title</title>

<link href="../static/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      th:href="@{/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/bootstrap.css}"/>

<script src="../static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"
        th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.1.1.js}"></script>
```

These standard tag values like `Page Title` or `href="../static/css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/bootstrap.min.css"` etc. are ignoring by controller and don't rendering on the page.

I'm wondering – is it just a good practice to leave them to improve code readability or it is better to remove them to clean up code?

Because for the compiler they are useless and have not any affect to the rendering result.

Comment: No, leave them. One of the main driving ideas of Thymeleaf is that the templates themselves are valid HTML. Without the attributes this would not be the case. The point being that you can test your code without running it through Thymeleaf.

Comment: For testing - sure it must exist! And when all the code is tested and ready for prod?

Comment: You _change your code_ between testing and production? Are you completely insane?

Comment: Oh i meant while developing. And may it be necessary to test the code without Thymeleaf?

Comment: I personally remove them.  While it's somewhat interesting to be able to view the html as a static page rather than running it through a server, I've rarely found a use for it in practice.

Answer (score 6):

This depends entirely on your development process.

You could keep the HTML attributes around in the early phases, while you are still trying to lay out the page using just your browser.

But, once you get to a point where you are using automated unit / web testing, you can safely remove the HTML attributes because this testing should always be using a prod-like environment (which would include thymeleaf).