# Thymeleaf + CSS+SpringBoot

Tags: css, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem with CSS and Thymeleaf.

In my Spring boot app, I have this structure:

- src/main/resource/static/css (for css files)
- src/main/resource/static/templates (for html file)

Now, with my html page named ErrorPage and css file named Layout.css, using Thymeleaf I have, in the head of ErrorPage:

```
<link href="../css/Layout.css" th:href="@{css/Layout.css}" type="text/css" />
```

But this does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you verify this, is your **ErrorPage** within **src/main/resources/static/templates** or **src/main/resources/templates**? If it's within the first one, it means it's handled as a **static resourc**e, which means Thymeleaf won't be used to render your page. If it's in the second one, then it can use Thymeleaf, but  it probably also means you're using it as a view within a controller. You have to work relatively upon the location of the controller, rather than the folder structure. Share your controller/configuration that uses this errorpage HTML.

Comment: What does not work? The ErrorPage does not render or it renders but the css file can't be downloaded? Do you use spring security?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Move your `template` folder right under `resources`:

- `src/main/resource/static/css` (for CSS files);
- `src/main/resource/templates` (for HTML templates).

Then correct the `link` tag as follows:

```
<link href="../static/css/Layout.css" th:href="@{/css/Layout.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Why do we need both 'href' and 'th:href' simultaneously?

Comment: We can easily remove HTML and use only Thymeleaf's attributes. Please read the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757974/should-we-remove-html-attributes-while-using-thymeleaf

Comment: Not working for me giving error "cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext"

Answer (score 4):

Move your template folder right under resources:

```
src/main/resources/static/css (for CSS files);
src/main/resources/templates (for HTML templates).
```

Then correct the link tag as follows (relative or absolute):

```html
<link href="../css/firstcss.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/secondcss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The old solution with static in front doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

The main culprit of this behaviour is a custom security configuration which is very likely you are doing in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter subclass.
If you use SpringBoot 2+ version you should add the following line in your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration

`.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()`