# Thymeleaf : relative url - without a webcontext

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I get this infamous error:

> cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement
>   the IWebContext

I have a spring boot application (without the web module) that creates pdf files.

I am planning to use an HTML file as a template, but I could not link the css file nor the image properly due to these url issues.

Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

  <head>
    <title>Company Invoice</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
          href="./css/company.css" th:href="@{./css/company.css}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p th:utext="#{home.welcome}">Welcome !</p>
     <img src="/images/gtvglogo.png" th:src="@{/images/gtvglogo.png}"/>
  </body>    
</html>
```

folder structure:

```
src/main/resources/templates/sample.html
src/main/resources/templates/css/sample.css
```

I googled a bit but I donT want to solve this via IWebContext.
Is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the structure and syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586841/thymeleaf-cssspringboot

Comment: @DimaSan Thanks for answer, i ve tried it exactly as mentioned, but it doesnT work with my case, i guess it s due to the context.

Comment: maybe yes, but it's really hard to say, probably if you could create a minimal example and share the link to GitHub, we would be able to help you.

Comment: was this ever solved? having the same issue

Comment: I ended up hardcoding the img in the HTML template i have in base64

Answer (score 1):

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base
>   "/a/relative/link" cannot be context
>   relative (/...) unless the context used for executing the engine
>   implements the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (template:
>   "templates/a-template" - line 6, col 13)
>
> 1 at org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder.computeContextPath
>   (StandardLinkBuilder.java:493)
>
> ...

The exception is thrown by the `org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder`. By providing a different implementation of `org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.ILinkBuilder` to the TemplateEngine we can avoid this expception

```java
TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setLinkBuilder(new ILinkBuilder() {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getOrder() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String buildLink(IExpressionContext context, String base, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        return null;
    }
});
```