# Thymeleaf with Spring Boot - Cannot Find Static Assets (CSS)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using the Thymeleaf template engine in my Spring Boot MVC application, but am having difficulty loading styless. The link is in the `header.html` file (located under resources/templates/fragments) and being referenced in `login.html` (under resources/templates). The stylesheet is located in the resources/static/css directory.

```
<head th:fragment="header">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/bootstrap.css" th:href='@{/css/bootstrap.css}' />
</head>
```

login.html

```
<html>
<header th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></header>

<body class="container">

    <h1>Login page</h1>
   // Code omitted for brevity

  </body>

</html>
```

I have a very typical directory structure:
[image]

Based upon this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586841/thymeleaf-cssspringboot) and other sources, is seems that application should be able to load the stylesheet using the specified link. However, this is not the case. Specifically, if I look in my browser's network tab, the request for the stylesheet returns a 302 (not a 404), but the styles are not applied. Furthermore, if I click "Style Editor" tab in Firefox, I receive a `Stylesheet could not be loaded: http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.css` message.

What might the issue be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
href="/static/css/bootstrap.css"
```

or even

```
href="static/css/bootstrap.css"
```

and in general this resource is available under

`http(s)://yourdomain/yourApplicationRoot/static/css/bootstrap.css`

As basicly this is the path that spring exposes static resources by default.

In your case, it will be `@{static/css/bootstrap.css}` (or with slash at the beginning)

Comment: Thanks for the response. As it turns out, the link noted in the opening post was correct. The issue was actually due to Spring Security; the 302 was a redirect to the login page. It was my understanding that Spring Security automatically added a filter to make these resources publicly accessible, but I guess that was not the case, which, in hindsight, is actually a sensible, secure default.

Answer (score 0):

your link tag should be

`<link href="../../static/css/bootstrap.css"
          th:href="@{css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>`